# No Method to_r For fixnum When Converting to Rational

Tags: ruby, textmate, irb

In irb:

```
(2**3).class #=> Fixnum
(2**3).to_r.class #=> Rational
```

In Textmate:

```
(2**3).class #=> Fixnum
(2**3).to_r.class #=> undefined method 'to_r' for 8:Fixnum
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Textmate and irb are using different versions of Ruby. [to_r](http://apidock.com/ruby/Float/to_r) was introduced in 1.9. See:

```
1.9.2 (main):0 > 1.to_r
=> (1/1)

1.8.7 (main):0 > 1.to_r
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_r' for 1:Fixnum
```